# How to find a file which is created after 5 mins exclude one sub directory which is owned by root user

Tags: command-line, find

Using "jbossapp" user I'm using this command to find ".stat" files which are created more than 3 minutes.

```
find /opt/jboss/* -mmin +3 -name "*.stat"
```

Recently there is a folder created in `/opt/jboss/` directory with root user now while using this command I'm getting 'permission denied' from the particular folder which is interrupting the search how do I exclude the particular folder which is having root privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
find /opt/jboss/* -type f -mmin +3 -name "*.stat" 2>/dev/null
```

The `2>/dev/null` will redirect the Standard Error Output to special file `/dev/null` to avoid displaying any errors.

Also we add `-type f` to look for **f**Iles only.

To excluding a directory use like below

```
find /opt/jboss/* -path /path/to/exclude -prune -o -type f -mmin +3 -name "*.stat" 2>/dev/null
```

also you can use `-not -path` as well.

```
find /opt/jboss/* -not -path /path/to/exclude -type f -mmin +3 -name "*.stat" 2>/dev/null
```

Even if you want exclude the find result from users who owned by root, use as follow:

```
find . \! -user root   .....
```

Comment: Hi AFSHIN,

i have been struggling for this solution from 4 days .. there is no enough word Thanks . But Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude folders owned by root, then prune them with find:

```
find /opt/jboss/. \
   -type d ! -name . -owner root -prune -o -type f -mmin +3 -name '*.stat' -print
```

To be read as: Inside the top directory  /opt/joss/ any folder that is not named ".", owned by "root" is not to be followed into. For everything else, we further constrain by picking regular files, older than 3 minutes, with extension ".stat" are to be printed to stdout.

Comment: Thanks for the solution i tried i m getting below error

find: unknown predicate `-owner'

Comment: @Kumar Change `-owner` to `-user`. Thanks,